# sum of 2 columns for each row in zend

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

How to get the sum of 2 columns for each row in zend. My code is-

```
$fieldArray = array('Jan','Feb', 'total'=>'Jan+Feb');
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$select = $db->select()
->from($this->_name,$fieldArray);
    die($select);
```

But it prints the query-
SELECT `Customer`.`Jan`, `Customer`.`Feb`, `Customer`.`Jan+Feb` AS `total` FROM `Customer`
and it gives error.

How to write the statement to get the result?

Comment: which type of error its shows ??

Comment: @naveengoyal SQL syntax error when I run it in mysql.

Comment: sql syntax is right as I think. what is datatype for fields? or just try brackets (Jan+Feb).

Comment: @naveengoyal solved. Actually there was some more fields for months, Oct and Dec, they were causing problem. Perhaps they are keywords in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
$fieldArray = array('Jan','Feb', 'total'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('Jan+Feb'));
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$select = $db->select()
->from($this->_name,$fieldArray);
    die($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

the query should be like

SELECT Customer.Jan, Customer.Feb, Customer.Jan+Customer.Feb AS total FROM Customer

Comment: yeah, its true but I asked for zend structure.